# Determine the equation of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

The problem is the following.
A ring of mass $m=1$ is moving along a circle of radius $R$ without friction.
It's tied to a spring (coefficient $k$) of natural length $0$. The other end of the spring is connected to a fixed point $A$ that'd at a distance $L>R$ from the center of the circle.

Determine the equation of motion for the ring.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These problems are best solved with the Euler-Lagrange equations.  Work in polar coordinates centred about the circle.  Then the ring is at $(R,\theta(t))$.  Its kinetic energy is,

$$T = \frac{1}{2} m R^2 {\dot{\theta}}^2 $$

From the spring there is potential energy.  Let $A$ be $(L,\phi)$ in polar coordinates. The potential energy is proportional to the distance between the two points $(R,\theta(t))$ and $(L,\phi)$.

$$\Delta^2 = \Delta x^2+\Delta y^2\\
\Delta x = R\sin\theta(t) -L\sin\phi \\
\Delta y = R\cos\theta(t) - L \cos\phi$$
So the potential energy is,

$$V = \frac{1}{2}k \Delta^2 $$

Substitute these into the Euler-Lagrange equations where $L=T-V$.  Note of course that the [Euler-Lagrange equations apply in all coordinate systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)#Example:_free_particle_in_polar_coordinates).

Hopefully this sketch is sufficiently precise that you can spot my (likely) errors.

Comment: Hey! I wasn't actually far off track in my mad man scribbles. Thanks!

Comment: Could this be further simplified by orienting the coordinate system in such a way that the coordinates of $A$ are $(L, 0)$?

Comment: Yes, you could do that and perhaps use $A$ rather than $L$ since you would just need the one parameter.